# Formula Required for Costs to date based on number of project days completed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to put together a template for project costs and am looking for a way to roll forward daily costs for each account code that avoids the need to change the formula on a daily basis.

I have all my account codes in column A then total daily costs in columns C/E/G etc for day 1/2/3 etc (Columns D/F/H have the calulation for that day's costs). Is it possible to put the current project day in a cell at the top of the 'cost to date' column and use this to pick up the costs for those days? ie

```
day 2 = C2+E2 
day 3 = C2+E2+G2
day 4 = C2+E2+G2+I2
```

etc

If it was just for me I'd be lazy and add each day as I went but as it's a template for general use I thought it would be useful to automate as far as possible.

Any help greatly appreciated
Thanks
Ian

Comment: Trying to insert a copy of the workbook but can't see how - any help on this?

Comment: I don't know what you're saying. Also I think I misinterpreted your question at first, ignore my first comment.

Comment: Put the cost-to-date as the first entry in the series (Col B or shift the daily numbers to the right and use Col C), so it is in a fixed position.  Then do a one-time formula creation where you add up every other cell for an arbitrarily large number of cells ( =C2+E2+G2...).  Copy that down the sheet for all account codes.  As the values are filled in, the total will reflect it.  The formula shown in the question gives you a running total for just one account.  If you want the values at the top, make the general formula the previous cum + daily cost (E1 =C1+E2; G1 =E1+G2), and pre-populate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use a VLOOKUP to look up the value of the day that is entered. Your range would be day 1 to day x and the calculated value for each day.

It would be helpful to see your workbook formulas for what you are trying to accomplish. Try using Ctrl+` (the button next to the 1 key on your keyboard) to show all formulas and then taking a screenshot to upload here.